# Create a Live Replica Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

Our Company is developing a website and it pulls information from our internal production servers. for added security I was asked if we could set up a new server and pull from that. I know I can have a nightly load done to populate the replica server but they want it updated at least every 15 minutes. does anyone have a good solution to keep a replica database as up to date as possible while the database is still in full use?

Note we are using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up replication if you have Enterprise Edition of SQL Server.

Otherwise, you can run a job every 15 minutes that uses SSIS to update the latest info.   Your source tables will need to have some kind "UpdatedOn" datetime column so you will know what data you need to import/update.

Comment: If I use the Replication will it work even while website users are pulling data? or will the data be unavailable during the replication?

Comment: Replication does not interfere with other usage.   It is by far the most efficient means of keeping a duplicate of your database, but it is also the most costly to set up.

Comment: this is the Version I am running but how do I set up replication I dont see that anywhere

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Setting up replication is much too big a topic for a Stack Overflow answer.   I would google exactly that:  "How to set up replication on SQL Server".  I'll warn you now, it's not as simple as flipping a switch.

Comment: Also, Enterprise Edition is not a requirement for transactional replication.